# Using specific Arabic font in Mpdf Library and getting the correct letters

Tags: fonts, mpdf

I am using droid and cairo fonts in mpdf but I am gettig corrupted letters, letters with diacritics should represented as a single character.

```
$mpdf = new Mpdf([
            'tempDir' => Yii::getAlias('@runtime'),
            'mode' => 'utf-8',
            'format' => 'A4',
            'defaultPageNumStyle' => 'arabic-indic',
            'setAutoTopMargin' => 'pad',
            'margin_top' => 0,
            'margin_header' => 0,
            'margin_footer' => 5,
            'margin_right' => 0,
            'margin_left' => 0,
            'margin_bottom' => 0,
            'fontDir' => array_merge($fontDirs, [
                '/ttfonts/',
            ]),
            'fontdata' => $fontData + [
                    'droid' => [
                        'R' => 'DroidKufi-Regular.ttf',    // regular font
                        'B' => 'DroidKufi-Bold.ttf',          // optional: bold font
                      'useOTL' => 0xFF,
                        'useKashida' => 75,
                    ],
                    'cairo' => [
                        'R' => 'Cairo-Regular.ttf',    // regular font
                        'B' => 'Cairo-Bold.ttf',          // optional: bold font
//                        'useOTL' => 0xFF,
                        'useOTL' => 0x80,
                        'useKashida' => 75,
                    ],
                    "myhacenfont" => [
                        'R' => "Hacen Liner Screen Regular.ttf",           // Regular - REQUIRED
//                        'useOTL' => 0xFF,
                        'useOTL' => 0x80,
                        'useKashida' => 75,

                    ],
//                    'default_font' => 'cairo'
                ],
//            'default_font' => 'droid'
        ]);
```

The text I want to print:

> لديك فهمٌ عميق لعواطفك والأسباب التي أدَّت إليها.

The output

[image]

I set `$mpdf->autoScriptToLang` to `true` but I got the text as normal font, and I want my specific font to be displayed instead.